# javascript comparacion arrays

Tags: javascript

como estan..estoy tratando de comparar 2 arrays los cuales uno es horas disponible(availableHours) y el otro es horas tomadas(takenHours) el problema que me surge es que cuando hago un for anidado y comparo a traves de un condicional, el proceso no me muestra las horas disponibles adecuadamente. solo me toma la primera y la segunda hora tomada es equivocada y las coloca como hora disponible.

```
availableHours = [
            { start: "8", end: "9" },
            { start: "11", end: "12" },
            { start: "14", end: "15" },
            { start: "17", end: "18" },
            { start: "20", end: "21" },
            { start: "23", end: "24" }
        ]


takenHours = [{ start: "8", end: "9" }, 
           { start: "17", end: "18" }
        ]
```

**como lo recorro y hago un condicional:**

```
for (let i = 0; i < store.availableHours.length; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < store.takenHours.length; j++) {
                    if (j === i) {
                        console.log(store.availableHours[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: ¿Lo que necesitas entonces es obtener las horas disponibles?, de igual manera estas comparando indices y deberías comparar valores

Comment: @AníbalJorquera correcto estimado, estoy tratando que solo me de horas disponibles...estuve tratando de comparar posiciones pero claro no es lo que se buscaba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te comentan en la otra respuesta, es cuestion de comparar los valores y puedes usar **for of** y **findIndex** o un solo **for**, la magia la hace el **finIndex** que lo que hace es buscar la propiedad con el mismo valor que tu definas, en el segundo array

```
var temp = [];

for(var item of availableHours){
      var index = takenHours.findIndex(a => a.start == item.start);
      if(index == -1){
         temp.push(item);
      }
}

console.log(temp);
```

Comment: vale estimado solucionado!

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas comparando los indices en lugar de los valores:

```js
availableHours = [
            { start: "8", end: "9" },
            { start: "11", end: "12" },
            { start: "14", end: "15" },
            { start: "17", end: "18" },
            { start: "20", end: "21" },
            { start: "23", end: "24" }
        ]


takenHours = [{ start: "8", end: "9" }, 
           { start: "17", end: "18" }
        ]


for (let i = 0; i < availableHours.length; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < takenHours.length; j++) {
                    if (takenHours[j].start === availableHours[i].start) {
                        console.log(availableHours[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: vale por el comentario @alanfcm el problema es que no me da como salida las horas que quedan despues de compararlas con las horas tomadas

Comment: Al código de @alanfcm solo tiene que verificar los diferentes `!==` en vez de aquellos que son iguales